# substring - add ... in the end if text is cut

Tags: php, html, wordpress, substr, strpos

I have a code on wordpress website (front-page.php), it's cut text and add "..." on title if text is over 35 characters. 
Cut is ok but the points is always visible. Is it possible to add only if text is cut?
Thank you!

```
<div class="bxpd">   
    <h2><span><?= substr($post_title,0,35); ?></span>
    <a href="<?= get_post_permalink($post_id); ?>">
        <?= substr($postData->post_title, 0, 35)."..."; ?>              
    </a>
    </h2>
    <p><?= substr($postData->post_content,0,strpos($postData->post_content, ' ', 150))."..."; ?> </p>
</div>
```

Comment: set a variable to true if the original length is more than 35. Show the dots conditionally only if that variable is true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class="bxpd">   
<h2><span><?= substr($post_title,0,35); ?></span>
<a href="<?= get_post_permalink($post_id); ?>">
    <?=
        substr($postData->post_title, 0, 35). (strlen($postData->post_title) > 35 ? "..." : ""); 
    ?>              
</a>
</h2>
<p><?= substr($postData->post_content,0,strpos($postData->post_content, ' ', 150))."..."; ?> </p>
```

Comment: I check it. http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b625fe31f7de321377773e48be9cc5977182eb99 What error you have? I edited this answer, maybe you use old version with bug

Comment: @CristianRossi I'm happy to help. If my answer is good, please accept it.

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust your code and put ... only if they are needed:

```
<div class="bxpd">   
                <h2><span><?= substr($post_title,0,35); ?></span>
                <a href="<?= get_post_permalink($post_id); ?>">
                <?= substr($postData->post_title, 0, 35)."..."; ?>

                </a>
                </h2>
                <p><?= substr($postData->post_content,0,strpos($postData->post_content, ' ', 150)).
(strlen($postData->post_content)>150?"...":""); 

?> </p>
           </div>
```